# 5-monitor setup with different size but same resolution

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, dpi, high-dpi

I have a 5-monitor setup with a large screen in the middle and 4x monitors that are ¼ of the main monitor size. The resolution is the same.

Is there a way to have the small monitors behave like they are ¼ of the resolution so I have a smooth transitions and can maximize pictures on them properly?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: great reply from phuclv,  but we also should know which monitor is which from the first step. If you skipped it, there is an Identify link on this screen too. Use it to identify your monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just open start menu, type `dpi` and click on display settings. Then click on each monitor and set the dpi appropriately. For example the main monitor 200% and the remaining ones 100%

[image: display settings]

[How to Change DPI Scaling Level for Displays in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: the maximum scaling this would allow me is 225% and i would need 400. And i cant use custom scaling cause it wont allow me to make 4 monitor 100% and 1 monitors at 400%

Comment: how big are your monitors? You said `4x monitors that are ¼ of the main monitor size` which means the area of the big monitor is 4 times the small ones, i.e. its dimensions will be twice the small ones, so you'll use 100% and 200%, not 100% and 400%